# Angular 4 auxiliary route not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have an application  where I have one login component and a home module. I want to have an aux route inside the home module.

As soon as the user logs in I am redirecting to the home route.

This is my app-routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Below is my home-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: HomeComponent,
                canActivate: [CanActivateGuard]
            },
            {
                path: '',
                outlet: 'aux',
                component: DashboardComponent,
                canActivate: [CanActivateGuard]
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

My expectation is that when the app is redirected to the home route `this.router.navigate(['/home']);` then both HomeComponent should be rendered (which is rendering right now) and DashboardComponent should be rendered (which is not rendering)

I tried all sort of hacks like providing a path to the component which need to be rendered inside aux route to 'dashboard' and from home component's ngOnInit method trying to redirect to the dashboard route `this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { aux: 'dashboard' }}]);`

But noting seems to work.
What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: NOTE: When Angular processes routes it goes with the first one it finds. It won't process multiple routes with the same path. In the above routes you defined two with an empty path. It will always only pick the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to activate both a primary route and a secondary (aux) route looks like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/home', { outlets: { aux: 'dashboard' }}]);
```

However, as far as I know there is still a bug in the routing and this syntax does not work. (At least it didn't for me about 2 months ago when I tried it.)

I had to instead use syntax like this:

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { 
                           primary: ['/home'], 
                           aux: ['dashboard'] 
}}]);
```

This syntax basically treats both routes as named routes and uses the Angular-defined name for the primary route ("primary"). You **don't** have to change your route configurations for this to work.

Comment: Instead of `this.router.navigate(['/home']);`, I tried above mentioned syntax, but its not working :( I am getting this error - `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '%2Fhome'`

Comment: and when I tried `this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { primary: ['home'], aux: ['dashboard']}}]);`, I got the following error - `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard'`

Comment: Looks like you don't have a dashboard route. You may have multiple issues here. Try changing your dashboard route path from '' to 'dashboard'.

Comment: If you want more information on how to work with routes, consider this course: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-2-getting-started-update/table-of-contents

Comment: I have changed the path from '' to 'dashboard' (I missed to mention this in my previous comment).

Comment: Can you do a plunker that demonstrates your issues?